# jQuery+ASP.NET: click = value in hidden field, clicking too fast

Tags: jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

I'm binding a click event to a hyperlink. Onclick the value (innertext) of the hyperlink is saved in a hidden field. With this value I'm working after page reload (ASP.NET).
It works - but the problem is:

If I click on link1, everything is okay.
If I click on link2, everything is okay.

If I click on link1 and then (very fast) on link2, the hidden field has the old value (of link1).

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

```
$(function () {
var innertxt = "";
$("span[id$='myLink']").bind("click", function () {
     innertxt = ($(this).text());
    if (innertxt == "myLinkText1" || innertxt == "myLinkText2") {
        $("input[id$='myHiddenField']").val(innertxt);
    } else { $("input[id$='myHiddenField']").val(""); }
  });
});
```

(Code in comination with ASP.NET page reload, meaning that after clicking a link $("span[id$='myLink']"), the page reloads.)

**// edit**

I already had an onclick (inline) event.
Apparently the binding was starting after the onclick event has been triggered and so it was too late.

I've put the code in the onclick inline event and it's working.

Thanks for your suggestions!

**// end edit**

Comment: are you cleaning the input value every time you click

Comment: I'm controlling the clicking with jQuery. So I've added in the first line (after ...("click", function () {...
) innertxt = "";, but no change at all.

Comment: i think you are doing it wrong. Please tell us what do u want to do?

Comment: I'm using a hidden field to only show files after clicking on a link that are related to the value in the hidden field.
It works, but only if I wait until the page has loaded completly. If I'm clicking too fast on one link and then on the other, the hidden field has the old value of the first link and the wrong files are shown.

Comment: Why are you attaching on spans though you said, they are hyperlinks?

Comment: Because it's easier to explain. But you are right.

Comment: What if you disabled the second link right after clicking the first one, so that it is re-enabled as soon as the postback completes? This prevents users from clicking the second link until the page has reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already had an onclick (inline) event. Apparently the binding was starting after the onclick event has been triggered and so it was too late.

I've put the code in the onclick inline event and it's working.

```
<span id="myLink" onclick="myCodeHere" />
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinkButton` control instead of `HyperLink` and set `CommandArgument` property to reflect which files must be shown.